# setTimeOut for elementRef

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm using Angular2. I have a div:

```
<div class="saved" #saved>
    <p>Saved</p>
    <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

I access it in ts:

```
@ViewChild("saved") public saved: ElementRef;
```

Next I display the block:

```
this.saved.nativeElement.style.display = 'block';
```

And then I would like to hide it after several seconds, but this part of my code isn't correct:

```
setTimeout(this.closeSavedWindow, 3000);
```

where

```
closeSavedWindow() {
    this.saved.nativeElement.style.display = 'none';
  }
```

The error is

> TypeError: this.saved is undefined

Comment: this has two different contexts you can debug this using console.log(this) inside and outside your function closeSavedWindoe()

Answer (score 0):

try `setTimeout(this.closeSavedWindow.bind(this), 3000);`

Answer (score 0):

The Problem you are facing is due to change in context. Inside closeSavedWindow() function this refers to the **Window object** and doesn't contain any property named saved. Hence the Error.

This can easily be fixed by binding the value of the context for function when calling it..

```
setTimeout(this.closeSavedWindow.bind(this), 3000);
```

Comment: Plunkr I used whilst testing.. https://plnkr.co/edit/JGtZYUN2xkQoJDM9n7BS?p=preview